# f:ValueChangeListener nullifying EJB injection

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, ejb, valuechangelistener

It loads stateList fine, but when I change the value of a state, it calls the backbean but addressBO is null.
How can I fix it? Any other way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="stateList" value="#{newUserController.address.stateID}">
 <f:selectItems value="#{addressController.stateList}" />
 <f:valueChangeListener type="controller.address.AddressController"/>
 <f:ajax event="change" render="cidadeList"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectOneMenu id="cityList" value="#{newUserController.address.cityID}">
 <f:selectItems value="#{addressController.cityList}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

BackBean

```
package controller.address;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class AddressController implements ValueChangeListener {

 @EJB
 private AddressBO addressBO;

 @PostConstruct
 public void firstThingToDo() {
  stateList = enderecoBO.loadStateListSelectItem();
 }

 @Override
 public void processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
  String state = (String) event.getNewValue();
  cityList = addressBO.loadCityList(state);
 }

}
```

The other backbean that set's the value of address and user that is not appearing in this case.

```
package controller.user;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class NewUserController {

 private Address address;
 private User user;

 @EJB
 private NewUserBO newUserBO;

 public void registerNewUser() {
  newUserBO.register(user, address);
 }

 public Address getAddress() {
  return this.address;
 }

 public void setAddress(Address address) {
  this.address = address;
 }

 public User getUser() {
  return this.user;
 }

 public void setUser(User user) {
  this.user = user;
 }

}
```

Comment: Your view code does not match your bean code and therefore your question/problem is very confusing. Please fix it (PS: please try to use English in code all the way, not only here on SO, but also in your real code, it'll greatly improve your English and greatly favour us, SO-pedians, and your future code maintainers). As far now I can only say: You do not need the `ValueChangeListener` at all. You're not interested in the old value.

Comment: The list of cities will be loaded depending on the value of the state. I kinda know English already, but still got some problems of writing what I want. And technical English isn't easy for me. We are still thinking in translate the code to English, but there's only Brazilians coding. We'll improve it to English when we have time. No time left by now :(

Comment: I don't need the old value, but, if not with `ValueChangeListener`, how could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you're creating a brand new instance of the class in the `<f:valueChangeListener>` tag. This is **not** the same instance as referenced by `@ManagedBean` and managed bean related annotations won't be invoked on that as well. You would rather like to use `valueChangeListener="#{addressController.processValueChange}"` on the `<h:selectOneMenu>` instead. But that doesn't immediately solve everything. The change is big that the second list don't behave as expected.

The second problem is that the value change listener method is invoked during *Validations* phase. This is the wrong moment to change/load model values. You should do this during *Invoke Action* phase. Use the `listener` attribute of `<f:ajax>`.

So:

```xml
<h:selectOneMenu id="stateList" value="#{newUserController.address.stateID}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{addressController.stateList}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{addressController.changeState}" render="cidadeList" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

with

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class AddressController {

    @EJB
    private AddressBO addressBO;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        stateList = enderecoBO.loadStateListSelectItem();
    }

    public void changeState(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        String state = (String) ((UIInput) event.getComponent()).getValue();
        cityList = addressBO.loadCityList(state);
    }

    // ... 
}
```